# In JavaScript's Underscore.js library what does 'context' mean and how do I use it?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm reading the documentation for the [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) library from [DocumentCloud](http://www.documentcloud.org/home).  Many of the functions take an optional `context` argument which is not explained.  My guess, as one familiar with Ruby is that this is similar to a Ruby `binding`.  And that it has something to do with what `this` means.  The extent of my JavaScript usage has been a few jQuery calls and some very boilerplate ajax.

My question: What does `context` mean and how should I use it?  A good answer should probably contain some information about how JavaScript works as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Javascript functions take a hidden `this` parameter which indicates the context in which the function was called.

Ordinarily, `this` is the global object (usually `window`).  However, when a function is called on an object, `this` will be the object that it was called on.

Underscore.js methods that take callback functions take an optional `context` parameter.  If this parameter is specified, the callback will be called with that `context`, meaning that `this` inside the callback will be equal to the context.

Comment: That answers the first part of the question.  Now, when should I use this ability, and and what should I set `this` to?  Or, to put it another way, it this something that is so rarely used that I should just ignore it unless it turns up in someone else's code?

Comment: @John: It's useful if you're passing a member function of your own object which needs to be called in context.

Comment: @SLaks: Can you provide a concrete example of `context` being used?

Comment: @jkndrkn: `_.whatever(myObj.someMethod, myObj)`